# JSColor automatic text color change

Tags: javascript, jscolor

I am using [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) and noticed that it automatically changes the text color based on the selected color. Example: If I chose a black background color, it would automatically change the text color to white. Is there anyway to disable this functionality?

Comment: @BriceCoustillas - thanks deleted

Answer (score 0):

Julian:

Comment out the following line of code from JSColor

```
this.styleElement = target; // where to reflect current color
```

which calls a function that sets the style of the target input field.

Answer (score 0):

try to find this:

```
   this.exportColor = function(flags) {
            if(!(flags & leaveValue) && valueElement) {
                var value = this.toString();
                if(this.caps) { value = value.toUpperCase(); }
                if(this.hash) { value = '#'+value; }
                valueElement.value = value;
            }
            if(!(flags & leaveStyle) && styleElement) {
                styleElement.style.backgroundImage = "none";
                styleElement.style.backgroundColor =
                    '#'+this.toString();
                styleElement.style.color =
                    0.213 * this.rgb[0] +
                    0.715 * this.rgb[1] +
                    0.072 * this.rgb[2]
                    < 0.5 ? '#FFF' : '#000';
            }
            if(!(flags & leavePad) && isPickerOwner()) {
                redrawPad();
            }
            if(!(flags & leaveSld) && isPickerOwner()) {
                redrawSld();
            }
        };
```

edit these lines:

```
                    styleElement.style.color =
                    0.213 * this.rgb[0] +
                    0.715 * this.rgb[1] +
                    0.072 * this.rgb[2]
                    < 0.5 ? '#FFF' : '#000';
```

to maybe

```
                styleElement.style.color =
                    0.213 * this.rgb[0] +
                    0.715 * this.rgb[1] +
                    0.072 * this.rgb[2]
                    < 0.5 ? '#000' : '#000';
```

if you want to make it slightly more neat

```
styleElement.style.color = '#000';
```

this works to hide the text completely

```
styleElement.style.color = 'transparent';
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `styleElement.style.color = 'transparent';` can remove text values from input fields but then it will not work for "font-color" attributes.

Instead I applied

```
styleElement.style.color = '#' + this.toString();
```

This removed text values from input fields and font-color attribute is also working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found following codes in source file:

```
if (this.valueElement) {
            if (jsc.isElementType(this.valueElement, 'input')) {
                var updateField = function () {
                    THIS.fromString(THIS.valueElement.value, jsc.leaveValue);
                    jsc.dispatchFineChange(THIS);
                };
                jsc.attachEvent(this.valueElement, 'keyup', updateField);
                jsc.attachEvent(this.valueElement, 'input', updateField);
                jsc.attachEvent(this.valueElement, 'blur', blurValue);
                this.valueElement.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
            }
        }
```

just comment those attachEvent
for example, if you don't want the textfield update its background color after pick color from color panel,just comment the "input" line.